# Flutter: error permission when delete file from removable storage

Tags: android, flutter, permission-denied

I have a file in this address:

`path = '/storage/084C-1C0F/Yalin - Deva Bize Sevisler [128].mp3'`

So after inserting this permission in android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I want to delete this file:

```
 checkPermission().then((value) {
  final dir = Directory(model.path);
  dir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
  BlocProvider.of<AllMusicBloc>(context)
      .add(DeleteDeviceMusic(model.id));
});

  Future<bool> checkPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    return true;
  }
```

but i got this error:

```
E/flutter (16660): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Deletion failed, path = '/storage/084C-1C0F/Yalin - Deva Bize Sevisler [128].mp3' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

A removable micro sd card is not writable for that path

Comment: How can i make writable that?It is possible ? @blackapps

Comment: No. Not with the classic file functions. You could use storage access framework however and let the user choose the file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Why is your file in that directory to begin with? Put it in the app specific directory on the card and you can delete it.

Comment: What to do if the user manually copies the file here? I mean, if the user connects the self phone to the computer and puts the file here, how can  delete the file through the application?@blackapps

Comment: What do you mean with 'here' ? When in app specific directory then yes.

Comment: here mean `/storage/084C-1C0F/` @blackapps

Comment: if user copies FILE here `/storage/084C-1C0F/` and want's to delete it from app.@blackapps

Comment: Why do you ask again? Read my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think Flutter not doing this by itself for doing this I used native code

for android :

```java
  private void removeFile(String path){

    File sd = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File image = new File(sd+ File.separator, path);

    if (image.exists()) {
      if (image.delete()) {
        System.out.println("file Deleted :" + image.getPath());
      } else {
        System.out.println("file not Deleted :" + image.getPath());
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` return `/storage/emulated/0/Download` but my file is in `External Memory Card`  and image variable return `/storage/emulated/0/Download/storage/084C-1C0F/Unit 06/Unit 6_Cycle 1_ Passage.mp3` path that is wrong @RezaEsfandiari